# Gitlab CI Heroku Deployment using dpl tool error

Tags: java, spring, heroku, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy my war file to heroku using Gitlab CI. I did all my changes, the war gets deployed but the Heroku logs show that webrunner jar cannot be found.

When I do **heroku logs --tail**, the log is shown as:

[image]

From the Gitlab deploy stage logs, I can confirm that I am on the right directory and necessary files has been generated.

[image]

Below is how my files look like.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: build
  tags:
    - able-tag
  script:
    - echo "build stage"
    - mvn package -B
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target
  retry: 1

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - able-tag
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - pwd
    - ls target
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$APP_NAME --api-key=$API_KEY
  dependencies:
    - build
```

**Procfile**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the issue. Code wise, there were no any issues. I created a new deployment in Heroku and then ran the pipeline and it worked like a charm.